# Start ELEVATED script from within script

Tags: powershell, uac, user-permissions

Hallo,

I'm playing around with Powershell (relative NewBie) and I'm looking for the easiest way to call a Powershell script with elevated rights from within another script.

I know of the runas verb for start-process which allows me to start a new script with a different account. My problem is, however, that under Vista (UAC active) every admin account has  [two access tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826699%28VS.85%29.aspx#account_needed_to_run_wmi_command-line_tools), a normal privilege one and an elevated one.

If I use the runas method, the second scripts gets started under the right account but with the non-elevated access token. Is there an easy way to control this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Ulrich

Answer (score 2):

Are you running PowerShell V2? If so check out the Microsoft [PowerShellPack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack) module. It has 'Start-ProcessAsAdministrator' which will run a process elevated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/63fd1c0d-da57-4fb4-9645-ea52fc4f1dfb/

This starts an elevation for the whole script.